# Preparing script for updating different values through view and running it in server side

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper, nohup

I have an update statement:

```
Update xxbl_conducting_section_v 
set volatge=11000, drawing_id=123 
where spid in (23, 11,22)
```

I need to run this script in nohup(server side for different voltages and different spids. There are 11000,22000,66000,13200 voltages.

I have an excel where it is written which spid will be which voltages. How to run this as a single script automatically?

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL tag suggests you use Oracle, while question says

> How to run this as a single script automatically?

From my point of view, you'll have to put some effort in it as I'm not sure you can do it *as is* without any programming.

You didn't post Excel file contents so I'll presume that it looks like

```
VOLTAGE   SPID
-------   ----
11000     25
11000     32
22000     120
13200     24
etc.
```

**One option** is to create `UPDATE` statements directly in Excel by writing a formula which contains fixed text (`update your_table set voltage =`, `where` clause) concatenated with cells' values that represent `voltage` value and `spid`. You can then save such a file as a `.sql` file and run it. Alternatively, as you're mentioning `nohup`, create a procedure which is basically just the same as that `.sql` file - you 'd just enclose bunch of `update` statements into `begin-end` block. Then schedule that stored procedure to run whenever you want (could be *right now*, if you want) using `dbms_scheduler` package.

**Another option** is to load Excel file contents into database. How? Save it as a CSV file and load it using SQL*Loader; or, create simple Apex application whose Wizard will help you in that task; or, use CSV file as external table. Once you have data in the database table, create a stored procedure which will loop through table's contents, dynamically create `update` statement and `execute immediate` it. As in previous option, you'd schedule that procedure.

**Why** "stored procedure" and "scheduling"? Because of nohup. Stored procedure runs in the database (i.e. on a database server, which is what you want), while database job lets you run it even though you aren't connected to the database (personally).